# High-quality LaTeX output format for website display with flexibility

Tags: pdf, links, output

I would like to display a document on my webpage that has a quality of a LaTeX output, such as PDF, PS, DVI. (Plain HTML does not have that quality -- the text is not as "nice" to read.)

However, I also would like to be able to play around with that document. For example, one thing I imagine is that when clicking on a link within the text, a figure corresponding to that link shows up on the webpage. If the text is plain HTML, I can imagine doing that with JavaScript. But with PDF, the text must be displayed in some PDF reader, and I know of no way to do that.

Is there a good solution?

Comment: HTML simply doesn't have the means to be as nice as a typeset document.  On the whole this is more of a pipe dream, but having figures put in a [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [dvisvgm](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/), which converts dvi to high-quality [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). Most modern browsers display svg files.

Unfortunately, dvisvgm doesn't support the conversion of hyperref specials (yet), although the svg format supports links. But you could edit the svg and add links or other fancy stuff.

Comment: Update: Since version 1.3 `dvisvgm` has support for `hyperref`.